# How can I show that this equality holds for $x \in (0,6)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I came up with this formula for computing an area $A$ as a function of $x \in (0,6)$:
$$A(x) = 2x\sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{4}-\arctan\left(\frac{10-x}{6-x}\right)\right)\sqrt{x^2-16x+68}$$

And I want to show that, for $x \in (0,6)$:
$$A(x) = -2x^2+16x$$

As you can see in the picture below, it seems to be true.

[image]

However, I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Please show your efforts in trying to answer the question.

Comment: There are none. I'm really sorry. I wish I had a few ideas, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Try using the sine difference formula. $\sin(\arctan(t))$ and $\cos(\arctan(t))$ are algebraic functions of $t$ on some intervals; see e. g. this [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716449/how-to-prove-that-sin-arctanx-fracx-sqrt1x2?rq=1) question. By the way, how did you get the formula?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with these formulas. I got it by trying to calculate the area of a rectangle inscribed in another rectangle. I wanted to see how to do it without using vectors.

Comment: Can you please upload a picture of those rectangles? It's very helpful as it would provide motivation for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first note that $$\sin(\arctan x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \quad \text{and} \quad \cos(\arctan x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$
(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716449/how-to-prove-that-sin-arctanx-fracx-sqrt1x2?rq=1) for the $\sin$ case; $\cos$ follows similarly.)

Also recall that $\sin(A-B) = \sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/how-can-i-understand-and-prove-the-sum-and-difference-formulas-in-trigonometry)). Now let $y = \frac{10-x}{6-x}$. Thus, \begin{align*}
A(x) &= 2x \sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} - \arctan y\right) \sqrt{x^2 - 16x + 68} \\
&= 2x \sqrt{x^2 - 16x + 68} \left(\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\cos(\arctan y) - \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\sin(\arctan y)\right) \\
&= 2x\sqrt{x^2-16x+68} \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \Big(\cos(\arctan y) + \sin(\arctan y)\Big) \\
&= \sqrt 2x\sqrt{x^2 - 16x + 68} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right) \\
&= \sqrt 2x\sqrt{x^2 - 16x + 68} \left(\frac{\frac{10-x}{6-x}+1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{10-x}{6-x}\right)^2 + 1}}\right) \\
&= \sqrt 2x\sqrt{x^2 - 16x + 68} \left(\frac{\frac{16-2x}{6-x}}{\sqrt{\frac{2x^2-32x + 136}{(6-x)^2}}}\right) \\
&= \sqrt 2x\sqrt{x^2 - 16x + 68} \left(\frac{16-2x}{\sqrt 2 \sqrt{x^2-16x+68}}\right) \\
&= 16x - 2x^2,
\end{align*}
as required.